# Http GET not triggering after RC4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

We have an application written in `Ionic2` and untill one week ago the app was running fine until we updated to new version of Ionic (Beta 11).

I'm using `Observable` and `map` for http calls, but all of sunden the http **get** is not being triggered.

That is the code I use for http call:

```
public getNavigation(target: string): Observable<Navigation> {

    console.log(target);

    return this.http.get(`data/${target}.json`)
        .map(response => response.json())
        .map((navigation: Navigation) => { return navigation; });
}
```

Here are my imports:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {Navigation} from "./navigation";
```

And here is my `package.json` dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.0",
    "ionic-angular": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "ionic-native": "^1.3.10",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  }
```

I also don't get any exception, simply nothing is happening and breakpoint will normally be hit, so I don't understand what is going on.

I didn't find anything related here, so what am I missing?

Comment: You have to subscribe http method to trigger the request

Comment: No sorry, it was working before. But thank you very much. I just found the solution I'll be posting it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I just had to import `rxjs/Rx`

`import 'rxjs/Rx';`

Hopefully this can help someone else as I had a big trouble. COde stopped working after the update, so this is definitely an update issue. Breaking changes?

Comment: This breaks tree shaking. Use `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'` instead